# Is it possible to rewrite a page URL from ID to name from an API?

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

Currently my URL looks like this: 
`http://countries.com/10`

I use `$id = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` to retrieve the id and then make an API-request with the ID. From the API I get the country which I want to replace the ID with.

Is this possible?

Comment: So the `/10` is the page on a WordPress site? And the API is a non-WordPress site? Is that correct? Are you trying to have, say,  http://example.com/australia/ load the data from the external API for that country? Is `/10` an actual page, or a custom rewrite rule?

Comment: Currently there is a custom rewrite rule, from ?id=10 to /10. So no, it's not an actual page. My `/` shows ALL the countries, and then `/10` gets information about Australia, for example.

Comment: But you're doing this with `add_rewrite_rule()` on a WordPress website, right?

Comment: I'm using a bought theme, so yes. I would assume that. I haven't touched the .htaccess file. Is there a simple way to find that function without going through the entire themefolder?

Comment: I'm confused. So you didn't make a rewrite rule? When I say is `/10` an actual page I mean a WordPress page. Is it a WordPress page with the ID 10? What theme is this?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. This theme have a page called `example.com/country`. First I was trying to use a param to retrieve the api, ex: `example.com/country?id=10`. Then I found it possible to use `example.com/country/10`, which works the same. Thats why I assume there is a custom rewrite.
`/10` isn't an actual page, and there is no Wordpress page with the 10 as id. I hope I made it a bit more clear!

Comment: Ok. It’s not really going to be easy for anyone here to help with custom functionality in a paid theme. And it’s not considered on topic anyway. You’ll need to contact the theme developers.